# Can Salesforce be configured as both Identity Provider and Service Provider at the same time

Tags: single-sign-on

I want to configure salesforce as both Sp and Idp so that user can have a seamless interaction with an external application.

Does Salesforce support this?

Comment: what's your specific business case? Salesforce supports both as IdP as well as SP

Comment: Are you saying you want Salesforce to be the IdP for the external app, but also to be a service provider to the same external app?

Comment: @DavidCheng You are absolutely right. We want salesforce to be the SP and IdP to the same external application